# Language is regular via regular expression

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I was wondering if this language is regular L={$a^{2m+k}b^{3n+l}c^{m+n}$ & $  
 k>2 $ & $ l \le 3$ & $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$} .I think the regular expression is :

$(aa)^*aaa(a)^*(bbb)^* \cdot ({e} \cup {b}  \cup {bb}  \cup {bbb} ) \cdot (c)^* $ .Am I correct?

Comment: No. Any time you see a language where, for example, the number of $c$s that are allowed depends on the number of $a$s and/or $b$s that appeared earlier in the string, your intuition should be that the language isn't regular. DFAs can't remember arbitrarily large numbers so they can't compare the absolute number of $a$s, $b$s and $c$s.

Comment: And what's your question?